# How do I change background of login screen?

Tags: login, desktop-background

Ubuntu allows us to set customized login screen (where it will show up only during logout session).

So, by default it shows just a purple background. I managed to find location directory of that file somehow.

But the thing is, during logout session, when we scroll wallpaper over to checkout user profile screen (DM).

It shows just a grey background, is there any possible way to setup custom image instead of simple grey color?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: the one you are referring to is lock/ unlock screen. https://askubuntu.com/a/1122957/739431

Comment: it depends on the desktop session you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 18.04 you are probably referring to the GDM login screen.

You want to edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`.
The line you're looking for is: `background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);`.

You can follow a more elaborate [tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-change-gdm-login-screen-background-in-ubuntu/).

You can look for the logout color you are seeing and replace it in the `ubuntu.css` file.