# Use login screen as lock / unlock screen

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, lock-screen, design

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122938/gnome-lock-screen-terminology) and I am asking myself if its possible to use my login screen as lock / unlock screen as I prefer the login screen visually. I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: @PRATAP Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: are you looking for tweakings or when you lock the screen, you want the same functionality of login page?? login page does not know who is logged in.. lock sceeen knows who is logged in.. when you see the login page..it belongs to gdm.. lock screen belongs to user..

Comment: can you just try at your lock screen by clicking the `login as another user` button